# Flutter error "the method 'toLowerCase()' was called on null"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, widget

I am creating a skype clone app in flutter and encountered an error when making the "search" functionality. I want to search my firebase db for other users by username or name returned in lowercase via a list that updates as you are typing. However, on first key stroke I encounter this error:

```
The method 'toLowerCase' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toLowerCase()
```

Here is the code for the search screen (the problem is under buildSuggestions):

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gradient_app_bar/gradient_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:skypeclone1/models/user.dart';
import 'package:skypeclone1/resources/firebase_repository.dart';
import 'package:skypeclone1/utils/universal_variables.dart';
import 'package:skypeclone1/widgets/custom_tile.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  FirebaseRepository _repository = FirebaseRepository();

  List<User> userList;
  String query = "";
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _repository.getCurrentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      _repository.fetchAllUsers(user).then((List<User> list) {
        setState(() {
          userList = list;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  searchAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return GradientAppBar(
      backgroundColorStart: UniversalVariables.gradientColorStart,
      backgroundColorEnd: UniversalVariables.gradientColorEnd,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + 20),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: TextField(
            controller: searchController,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                query = val;
              });
            },
            cursorColor: UniversalVariables.blackColor,
            autofocus: true,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 35,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {
                  WidgetsBinding.instance
                      .addPostFrameCallback((_) => searchController.clear());
                },
              ),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Search",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 35,
                color: Color(0x88ffffff),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildSuggestions(String query) {
    final List<User> suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? []
        : userList.where((User user) {
            String _getUsername = user.username.toLowerCase();
            String _query = query.toLowerCase();
            String _getName = user.name.toLowerCase();
            bool matchesUsername = _getUsername.contains(_query);
            bool matchesName = _getName.contains(_query);

            return (matchesUsername || matchesName);


          }).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
        User searchedUser = User(
            uid: suggestionList[index].uid,
            profilePhoto: suggestionList[index].profilePhoto,
            name: suggestionList[index].name,
            username: suggestionList[index].username);

        return CustomTile(
          mini: false,
          onTap: () {},
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(searchedUser.profilePhoto),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          title: Text(
            searchedUser.username,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            searchedUser.name,
            style: TextStyle(color: UniversalVariables.greyColor),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: UniversalVariables.blackColor,
      appBar: searchAppBar(context),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: buildSuggestions(query),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I omit the toLowerCase() widget from buildSuggestions, I get a similar error:

```
The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains("h")
```

*h was my keystroke

Comment: is this `userList = list;` null? Check using print(userList);

Comment: When I print, the output is `I/flutter ( 7963): [Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User']`. Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: Are u using the bloc pattern?

Comment: Hello, yes I am, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your build functions should be something like this where it runs buildSuggestions only when userList is not empty.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: UniversalVariables.blackColor,
      appBar: searchAppBar(context),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: userList.isEmpty?Container():buildSuggestions(query),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, the same error is being thrown. Would it help to share my main.dart file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your input data. Because some your input data are nullable, so it occur errors
You should check this code:

```
final List<User> suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? []
        : userList.where((User user) {
            String _getUsername = user.username.toLowerCase();
            String _query = query.toLowerCase();
            String _getName = user.name.toLowerCase();
            bool matchesUsername = _getUsername.contains(_query);
            bool matchesName = _getName.contains(_query);

            return (matchesUsername || matchesName);


          }).toList();
```

Or you can fix as below:

```
          userList.where((User user) {
            if (query != null || user.username != null || user.name != null) {
              String _getUsername = user.username.toLowerCase();
              String _query = query.toLowerCase();
              String _getName = user.name.toLowerCase();
              bool matchesUsername = _getUsername.contains(_query);
              bool matchesName = _getName.contains(_query);

            return (matchesUsername || matchesName);
            } else { return false; }

          }).toList()
```

Comment: I applied this fix and the same error is being thrown. Perhaps there's somewhere else I should put an else statement? Should I include my main.dart file here as well?

Answer (score 0):

Hey in the above code the error 
The method `'toLowerCase'` was called on null.

> Receiver: null Tried calling: toLowerCase()

is caused due to irregular users data in database

To solve this try deleting the users collection in database or delete irregular collections and login fresh